# Fragment Button is found by Activity's findViewById instead of Fragment's inflated view.findViewById

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-activity, include

I'm seeing this strange behavior and couldn't find anything similar to this.

So I have a parent `Activity` and inside is a `Fragment`, which I'm including in parent via `include` element and then in parent's `onCreate`, create `Fragment` and replace it with this `include` layout (Tell me if this is a right way? I was using `FrameLayout` but then switched to `include` and defined an `id` to it).

## Activity

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.sourcey.materiallogindemo.CustomerDetailActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/layout_bottom_bar"
        layout="@layout/fragment_customer_detail" />

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

        </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

## Fragment

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.sourcey.materiallogindemo.CustomerDetailFragment"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

<!-- THIS IS THE CULPRIT -->
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_update_position"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/sku_list"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:context="com.sourcey.materiallogindemo.CustomerDetailFragment"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_s_k_u_item" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`Fragment` is `inflate`d correctly but when I do this inside `onCreateView`

```kotlin
rootView.btn_update_position.setOnClickListener {
    // ... log something
}
```

and press the `Button`, it doesn't do anything? Even though most findings were led to this suggestion that I should `inflate` the `view` and then set `onClickListener`.

I also tried doing these

```kotlin
rootView.findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.btn_update_position).setOnClickListener {
    // ... log something
}
```

and

```kotlin
val button = rootView.findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.btn_update_position)
button.setOnClickListener {
    // ... log something
}
```

but none of them works.

I also tried above approaches in `onViewCreated` to see if maybe I was not getting the reference but no errors were thrown and no reaction was coming.

Only thing that works is this

```kotlin
activity?.findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.btn_update_position)
    ?.setOnClickListener {
         // ... log something
}
```

I'm trying to understand why this happens? Could this be the issue of using `include` the `Fragment`?

**NOTE** I'm not a pro in android just do hobby work in it so don't know very deeply about it.

**EDIT** As you can see I have a `RecyclerView` in `Fragment` layout, I'm inflating the layout and then setting its adapter items which seems to work fine opposed to button.

```kotlin
rootView.sku_list.adapter = Adapter()
```

Comment: I think you should add a FrameLayout to the fragment_customer_detail.xml which will be the fragment contrainer

Comment: I had but I want to know what’s the difference between them is it the other is not a layout ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm bit confused about what you want to do here

First,`<include>` doesn't create new view, it just include the xml into the parent xml file so basically it still on activity and you need activity to findViewById

Second, about your question what different between FrameLayout and `<include>`.

With `<include>` like i said above, it just add xml file to the parent file, the main usage is for re-use layout (you can include it anywhere) .

With FrameLayout, from official doc : "FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item". E.g : you want your layout have a header and footer for all screen, only the middle part change so place a frame layout at middle then load different view for each screen, because that flexibility frame layout usually use for display fragment (you can google how to use frame layout for more details)

Comment: right, so if I need to keep elements reference in fragment I should use `FrameLayout`. I was confused about inflation as I was inflating the included layout in `Fragment` and then replacing it with `include` tag

Comment: I should have probably mentioned in question, I have a `RecyclerView` in `Fragment` layout as well and I'm setting its adapter after inflating it from view as I tried to do for button and it seems to work fine. i.e. items are loaded in `Fragment` and draw on screen